# Jquery how to select all element but children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code like that:

```
<div id="mn">

   <span></span>
   <span> <span></span></span>
   <span></span>
   <span> <span></span></span>
   <span></span>

</div>
```

when i use:

```
$("#mn").each(function(index, element) {

)};
```

it selects all span tags and span inside span tags, how do i select only parents span tags.

Comment: What does "all element but children" mean? Also `$("#mn").each` should return one match since IDs must be unique, so there's no point in even using each here. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Your code `$("#mn")` is not going to select the spans....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this way:

```
$("#mn > span").each(function(index, element) {


)};
```

This will only give immediate child span elements.

[**JQUERY DOCS**](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

[Use the child selector `parent > child`](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

```
$("#mn > span")
```